# Additional folder where will Media Library look for files

Tags: functions, media-library, directory

I have additional folder (images/) in wp-content/uploads/ directory to store theme images (I heard it is good practice to place them in upload directory) and I want Media Library to list this files because I might need to reuse them somewhere else. Is there a way to tell Media Library to look for files in whole uploads directory (or manually add directories to look in) maybe using functions.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Media library doesn't directly pull from the `uploads` folder. It reads in Attachments, which place their attached media in the `uploads` folder. If you want to access them through WordPress, you will need to upload them as Attachments.

Comment: Great. I have actually found a plugin that can import files from any folder into database which is a great work around this problem. I wouldn't know about this without your answer. Thanks. And this is the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/

Answer (score -1):

You can customize the upload location in the `wp-config.php` file.
Just before the line that goes

> `require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);`

add `define('UPLOADS', 'path/to/new/folder');`.